# Proving $ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } f_n(1) $ converges when $ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } f_n(x) $ converges uniformly

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I have a question which I tried solving for a few hours.
My only solid direction so far is trying using Cauchy.

Let $(f_n(x))$ be a series of continuous functions in $[0,1]$.
Prove; If $ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }  f_n(x) $ converges uniformly at $[0,1)$, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty }  f_n(1) $ converges.

Thank you in advance, been trying a lot solving this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "converges uniformly on $(0,1)$ (or $[0,1)$)"? Because otherwise, uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ implies pointwise convergence on $[0,1]$, and $1$ is in there.

Comment: @ClementC. Correct, I was wrong, Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

*Maybe not the most elegant, but a detailed way to get it by "splitting $\varepsilon$."*

Let $S_n\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$, for $n\geq 1$ and $x\in[0,1]$. Since the $f_n$'s are continuous on a compact set, they are *uniformly* continuous, so is $S_n$. Moreover, by assumption the sequence $(S_n)_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$, to a limit which we will call $S\colon(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Note that $S$ is then *uniformly* continuous *(can you see why?)*, and thus can be extended on $[0,1]$ to a continuous function. I.e., we get that $S$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

- Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. By uniform convergence, there exists $n_\varepsilon\geq 1$ such that, for every $n\geq n_\varepsilon$, $\sup_{x\in(0,1)} |S_n(x)-S(x)| \leq \varepsilon/3$.
- Moreover, since $S_{n_\varepsilon}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists $\delta_\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $x\in(1-\delta_\varepsilon,1)$, $|S_{n_\varepsilon}(1)-S_{n_\varepsilon}(x)| \leq \varepsilon/3$. (Using continuity at $1$).
- Moreover, since $S$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$, there exists $\delta'_\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $x\in(1-\delta'_\varepsilon,1)$, $|S(1)-S(x)| \leq \varepsilon/3$. (Using continuity at $1$).

By the triangle inequality, combining the two inequalities for $S_{n_\varepsilon}$, we get that for all $x\in(1-\min(\delta_\varepsilon,\delta'_\varepsilon),1)$,
$$
|S_{n_\varepsilon}(1)-S(1)| \leq \varepsilon
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows that the sequence $(S_n(1))_n$ converges, which is what we wanted.

Comment: This is the correct approach (+1).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Two small questions - Why is $     n_\varepsilon \geq 1 $?  Also, why you always split $\varepsilon/3$?

Comment: @Dave I wrote $n_\varepsilon$ to show that $n$ depends on $\varepsilon$ ("for every $\varepsilon$, there exists an $n$ such that...") As for the $\varepsilon/3$: when using the triangle inequality, we end up summing 3 terms: I chose each to be $\varepsilon/3$: so that their sum is $\varepsilon$ (to have a "clean" end statement).

Comment: Clement, in the first question - I meant why is $n$ bigger than 1?

Comment: @Dave It's an integer, we don't really get to choose it. But if your question is "why can't it be 0", then it boils down to where you start your indexing :). But in any case, if some $n$ works, then any larger integer works too -- so if $0$ works, then $1$ works too.

Answer (score -1):

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$, then $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ s.t. $$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(x) \right| < \epsilon$$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. Furthermore $\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ (and can therefore be continued to $[0,1]$) since (by uniform continuity of $f_n(x)$ on $(0,1)$ and uniform convergence of $f(x)$) $\forall \epsilon'>0$ there is $N'>N$ and $\delta(N')=\delta'>0$, s.t. $\forall x,x' \in (0,1)$ with $|x-x'|<\delta'$ $$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(x)-f_n(x') \right| \leq \sum_{n=N}^{N'-1} \underbrace{\left| f_n(x)-f_n(x') \right|}_{<\frac{\epsilon'}{N'-N}} + \underbrace{\left|\sum_{n=N'}^\infty f_n(x)\right|}_{<\epsilon'} + \underbrace{\left|\sum_{n=N'}^\infty f_n(x') \right|}_{<\epsilon'}<3\epsilon' \, .$$

For $x=1-\delta$ with $\delta >0$ this gives
$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(1) \right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(1) - f_n(1-\delta) \right| + \left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(1-\delta) \right|<2\epsilon$$
The second term is less than $\epsilon$ by definition of uniform convergence, while the first term can be made less than $\epsilon$ for small enough $\delta$ due to the continuity of $\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(x) \right|$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: "which implies by continuity" $\leadsto$ by continuity of what, though?

Comment: You are using  $\lim_{\delta \to 0+} \left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(1-\delta)\right| =\left| \sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(1)\right|$ and this is essentially what needs to be proved in this problem.

Comment: The function $\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(x) \right|$ can not be discontinuous at $x=1$ when the $f_n$ itself are continuous...

Comment: @Diger That is not obvious, given that you sum infinitely many of them. This is exactly the type of statement that requires a proof.

Comment: tbh, using your notation this is precisely the same assumption you put in there: "S is continuous on [0,1]." Assuming that $S$ is continuous on [0,1] basically must make $S$ converge, since what else is it supposed to do when $|S(x)-S(1)|<\epsilon$? This is true for all $\epsilon>0$ and when $S(x)$ is convergent then so must be $S(1)$, otherwise this inequality can not hold.

Comment: @Diger This is not an assumption. I... gave a justification for that.